# Condition for Ehresmann connection to be linear

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, connections

I am trying to get more familiar with Ehresmann-connections by looking at how they look like in local trivializations. I am roughly aware of the abstract theory, but not everything is immediately clear, hence this "investigation".

---

Now, let $M$ be a smooth $n$ dimensional (real) manifold and let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a rank $k$ vector bundle. Local trivializations are identified with local frames of $E$. A generic local section is written as $\psi=\psi^Ae_A$ and the index notation conventions of Einstein and Schouten are employed.

A bundle chart for $E$ then looks like $(x^\mu,\psi^A)_{\mu=1,...,n;\ A=1,...,k}$, with a common domain $U$ for both the local chart on $M$ and the local trivialization of $E$ (this domain will be left implicit in this post).

If a Koszul connection on $E$ is given locally by $$ \nabla_\mu\psi^A=\partial_\mu\psi^A+\omega_{\mu\ \ B}^{\ A}\psi^B, $$ then this connection determines an Ehresmann-connection on $E$ by letting $$ H_{(x,\psi)}=\text{span}(D_\mu), $$ where $$ D_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}-\omega_{\mu\ \ B}^{\ A}\psi^B\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi^A}. $$

This much is clear. However, something's unclear if I try to work *the other way around*.

We can define the canonically existing vertical distribution as $$ V_{(x,\psi)}=\text{span}\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi^A}\right\}, $$ and is easily verified that this is independent of the local trivialization. Now, let's try to define a horizontal distribution locally as $$ H_{(x,\psi)}=\text{span}\{D_\mu\}, $$ where I look for $D_\mu$ in the form $$  D_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}+Q^A_\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi^A}.$$

The reason I am looking for the horizontal frame in this form is that, the presence of $\partial/\partial x^\mu$ will ensure that $D_\mu$ can never be vertical.

**Question 1:** If I am interested in the *most general* Ehresmann connection on $E$ (linearity is **not** assumed), is this true that *any* horizontal distribution has a frame in this form?

Now, going further, I want to ensure that my connection is *linear*, in the sense that parallel transport is linear.
It is natural, then that I should demand $Q^A_\mu(x,\psi)$  to have only linear dependence on the fiber coordinates, so $Q^A_\mu=-\omega^{\ A}_{\mu\ \ B}(x)\psi^B$. This will obviously give back what I started from (the covariant derivative).

My problem is that Lee (Jeffrey, author of [Manifolds and Differential Geometry](http://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-107), not to be confused with John Lee) states in the aforementioned book that the only condition for an Ehresmann connection on $E$ to be a *linear* connection is that it respects *scalar multiplication*, eg. that $(S_\lambda)_*H_{(x,\psi)}=H_{(x,\lambda\psi)}$ where $S_\lambda$ is multiplication by the scalar $\lambda$.

I guess that in my own approach/notation, this means that $Q^A_\mu(x,\psi)$ is a homogenous function (of degree 1) of $\psi$. However, as far as I am aware, homogenity does not necessarily imply linearity.

**Question 2:** What is the necessary condition for $H$ to be a linear Ehresmann-connection? Is Lee right or wrong? If he is right, then how does the form $D_\mu=\partial_\mu-\omega_{\mu\ \ B}^{\ A}\psi^B\partial_A$ come from a homogenous $Q^A_\mu$? Am I doing everything correctly?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. The $H_{(p, v)}$ defining the Ehresmann connection are assumed to be "horizontal" i.e. the projection $H_{(p, v)} \to T_p M$ has full rank. Then if you pick a basis of $H_{(p, v)}$ and extend it to a basis of $T_{(p, v)} E$ by adding vertical vectors you will see that the basis for $H_{(p, v)}$ had to be of the form $ D_\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}-Q_\mu^A \frac{\partial}{\partial\psi^A}. $